# Accessible jquery tabs - direct link to tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accessibility

I have tabs on my page. The code for them is following:

```
$('ul#tabs li a').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var counter = 1;

        $("ul#tabs a.current").removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');

        $('.contentBox').not('.' + id).hide();

        $('.contentBox.' + id).show();

        if(id=='all'){
            $('.contentBox').show();
        }

        $('.contentBox').removeClass('last');

        $('.contentBox').each(function() {          
            if(counter%4==0) {
                $(this).addClass('last');
            }

            if($(this).css('display')!='none'){
                counter++;
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Now I would like to add possibility to direct linking so that user can copy the link to certain tab and paste it to address bar and it goes to that tab/div straight away. Like this:

```
TabLinkforContent1 TabLinkforContent2 TabLinkforContent3
```

Atm when page is loaded it shows the `TabLinkforContent1` and now user needs to click for example the `TabLinkforContent3` link to vie Content on `div3`. I want to change the code so that use can copy `TabLinkforContent3` address and give it to someone and if he uses that url it shows automatically content `div3`. So url would be something like `www.domain.com/page#div3` i guess. But I dont know how to change the javascript code.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your links are ID based, you can just put this after your current code:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul#tabs li a').click(function(){
    $("ul#tabs a.current").removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('.contentBox').show().removeClass('last');
    if (this.id !='all') $('.contentBox').not('.' + this.id).hide();

    $('.contentBox:visible').each(function(i) {          
      if ((i+1)%4==0) $(this).addClass('last');
    });
    return false;
  });
  if(location.hash) $(location.hash).click();
});
```

This will trigger the `click` handler you just bound on the `<a id="something">` element the has identifies.  Combined with your current code shortened down:

Comment: This actually doesnt work. I tried by just addning the if(location part and it didnt work, and then the whole code and the tabs stopped wroking as well.

Comment: @dmitri - do you have an example page you can provide a link to?

Comment: Unfortunatly no, its only on my local atm

Comment: I used Nick Craver's idea and it worked just dandy. Thanks Nick!